# Mongo db driver doesn't update record

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go-driver

I'm creating an app using microservice architecture with go and mongodb. Now I'm trying to make a crud with users, but I faced with a small problem. When I try to update the record nothing changes. I don't know what can be the problem, cuz I took it from official documentation.

So here's my code:

**user_service.go**

```golang
type UserService struct {
    protos.UserServiceServer
}

func (s *UserService) Update(_ context.Context, request *protos.UpdateRequest) (*protos.GetResponse, error) {
    resultUser, err := user.Update(request)
    if err != nil {
        return response.CreateErrorGetResponse("couldn't update user"), nil
    }
    return response.CreateGetResponse(resultUser), nil
}
```

**user_funcs.go**

```golang
func Update(request *protos.UpdateRequest) (*store.User, error) {
    claims, err := jwt_func.DecodeJwt(request.Token)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    filter := bson.D{{"_id", claims.Id}}
    update := parseRequest(request)
    err = repository.Update(filter, bson.D{{"$set", update}})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    user, err := repository.GetById(claims.Id)
    return user, nil
}

func parseRequest(request *protos.UpdateRequest) bson.D {
    var update bson.D
    if request.Nickname != "" {
        updateBson(&update, "nickname", request.Nickname)
    }
    if request.PhoneNumber != "" {
        updateBson(&update, "phone_number", request.PhoneNumber)
    }
    if request.Email != "" {
        updateBson(&update, "email", request.Email)
    }
    if request.Password != "" {
        hashedPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(request.Password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        updateBson(&update, "password", string(hashedPassword))
    }
    return update
}

func updateBson(data *bson.D, key string, value interface{}) {
    *data = append(*data, bson.E{Key: key, Value: value})
}
```

**user_repo.go**

```golang
func Update(filter bson.D, updateData bson.D) error {
    _, err := config.DBCollection.UpdateOne(config.DBContext, filter, updateData)
    if err != nil {
        config.ErrorConsoleLogger.Println("Error: couldn't update user")
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

**UserService.proto**

```
message UpdateRequest {
    string token = 1;
    string nickname = 2;
    string login = 3;
    string email = 4;
    string phoneNumber = 5;
    string password = 6;
}

service UserService {
    rpc Update(UpdateRequest) returns (GetResponse);
}
```

So what can be the problem? If you know, please tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: How was the user created? Is the _id a string, or is it an ObjectId?

Comment: It was created like objectId

Comment: Claims.Id is likely a string. Convert that to ObjectId